# Save data in ajax form yii2

Tags: ajax, forms, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to save data in two tables. The form being used is an ajax form with ajax request.

I want to obtain two values 'Task_ID' and 'Employee_ID' from the form and then save it to another table.

Controller Code is below

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    $model = new Activity();  
    $empModel = new Tasksemp();
    //$tasksModel = new Tasks();

    if($request->isAjax){
        /*
        *   Process for ajax request
        */
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        if($request->isGet){



            return [
                'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                'content'=>$this->renderAjax('create', [

                    'model' => $model,

                    $model->finish_date = date('y-m-d'), //give default date as current along with date picker option

                    $empModel->Task_ID = $model->Task_ID, //<----Error here. The value of Task_ID and Employee_ID is null.
                    $empModel->Employee_ID = $model->Employee_ID,
                    $empModel->save(false),

                ]),
                'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])

            ];





        }else if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()){
            return [
                'forceReload'=>'#crud-datatable-pjax',
                'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                'content'=>'<span class="text-success">Create Activity success</span>',
                'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                        Html::a('Create More',['create'],['class'=>'btn btn-primary','role'=>'modal-remote'])

            ];         
        }else{           
            return [
                'title'=> "Create new Activity",
                'content'=>$this->renderAjax('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'empModel' => $empModel,
                ]),
                'footer'=> Html::button('Close',['class'=>'btn btn-default pull-left','data-dismiss'=>"modal"]).
                            Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','type'=>"submit"])

            ];         
        }           
    }else{
        /*
        *   Process for non-ajax request
        */
        if ($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Activity_ID]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

}
```

I need to obtain the two values after the ajax form has been saved or anyway way I can get the values and save in the ajax form?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: `$model->Task_ID` and `$model->Employee_ID` are null because upto that line `$model` is empty. You just created empty model _($model = new Activity();)_ and haven't set any value! I didn't understand the `obtain two values 'Task_ID' and 'Employee_ID' from the form` part. Where do you want them??

Comment: Ok. I want the Task_ID and Employee_ID from the Form. When the user tries to create a new entry and clicks on submit, I want these two values from the form to be saved in the $empModel->Task_ID and $empModel->Employee_ID

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote incorrect code.
Is not recommend (strictly) perform "=" operator and methods within `[ ... ]` statement.
Then you not load any values to `Activity` model.

```
if ( $request->isGet ){

    $model->finish_date = date('y-m-d'); //give default date as current along with date picker option

    // loading values from form

    $empModel->Task_ID      = $request->get('name_of_form_input_that_contains_Task_ID'); 
    $empModel->Employee_ID  = $request->get('name_of_form_input_that_contains_Employee_ID');

    $empModel->save(false);

    return [
        'title'   => "Create new Activity",
        'content' => $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            // any other data
        ]),
        'footer' => '' // ..
    ];

}
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but I get an error :- "name":"PHP Warning","message":"Creating default object from empty value","code":2,"type":"yii\\base\\ErrorException"

Comment: This is not comlete code. This is only part of your code ("if statement").

Comment: Yes but I am not assigning any more values to any model ahead in the other part of the code. What do you suggest I should do to get this working?

Comment: You should create both models.